# CSS alignment and positioning

Tags: html, css

My div with text, buttons, gif and image is set to center, but how to set another div left of it, without new line than left?

Image explanation : https://prnt.sc/faolm5

Comment: use `float:left` CSS property

Comment: Can you add the code snippet

Comment: Please share your html and css

Comment: use float:left for the new element

Comment: for this, you should follow [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

You should check this out. [LearnLayout](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) It will help you. You can use the below CSS as well.

**Example one**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Example two**

```
div {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left`

```
#div1 {
  width: 50px;
  height:  50 px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}

#div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height:  50 px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1">
    I am first!
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    I am second!
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/L53d5RoIRsZw0O4vH0nC?p=preview)**